# Adding local assets keeps loading forever in spark ar tool

Tags: textures, assets, mesh, spark-ar-studio

Whenever I try to load any local asset to my project, it just keeps loading forever and neither loads nor the uploading stops and if I try to do anything else on top of it, the application hangs. This is happening everytime and I have to manually close application and try again yet for the same result. 
Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I was doing dragging and dropping of the headOccluder.obj directly onto the face tracker. So It was taking so much time. I followed that procedure since i had seen someone doing same in a tutorial video. It had worked for them but somehow not for me.
Now I first dragged it and dropped into assets panel and from there dragged and dropped into face tracker. now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I never use the standard Spark AR Studio compression because of such bugs.

I just do this:

1) I compress the textures myself with "tinypng"

2) Add them to the project and immediately put "No Compression" for the added texture

Comment: Hi Will this work for all type of assets? I was actually trying to load headOccluder.obj recently.