# Spark Ar headOccluder.obj loading not happening

Tags: assets, spark-ar-studio

When I am trying to load headOccluder.obj from my local, It keeps processing and doesn't load. I am stuck here from few days. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding local assets keeps loading forever in spark ar tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620764/adding-local-assets-keeps-loading-forever-in-spark-ar-tool)